# How can I make Chromium open apt links with xdg-open?

Tags: apt, chromium, downloads, apturl

I installed [this extension](https://chrome.google.com/extensions/detail/oljmaangfgmmokjpnojhfblppgeijikp)
because I wanted to open apt links clicked in Chromium with `xdg-open`.

I have looked at [this help page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/AptURL) but haven't been successful. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

I have downloaded Google Chrome 8.0.552.215

Then i installed the suggested extension from your link.

then i went to http://www.apturl.net/ i searched for avidemux for example.

I clicked on it and it started the apt manager. No problem.

I suggest check your google chrome version which would be the only different thing.

Tested with ubuntu 10.04, 10.10 and kubuntu 10.10

EDIT: Tried playdeb.net and getdeb.net. Both worked. Am using the chrome version i mention above. Let me know if you can work with this version just in case. Downloaded Google Chrome from http://www.google.com/chrome

EDIT2: Updated to 8.0.552.224. Still works. No problem here. Please confirm when you update how it went.

Comment: Thanks is working now, i don't know if i rebooted or what i did, but is working, im using last chromium too.

Answer (score 0):

This question should help you select which browser URLs will be opened in:

[How to set which application is launched by xdg-open?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18418/how-to-set-which-application-is-launched-by-xdg-open)