# How can I set which application is launched by 'xdg-open'?

Tags: chromium, default-browser, xdg-open

I have run `update-alternatives` as well as the GNOME *Preferred apps* selection thing. And all point to have the Chromium browser as the default. Yet, when I run `xdg-open http://askubuntu.com`, Firefox is launched! Similarly, [Emacs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs) and [Bazaar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bazaar_%28software%29) (`bzr`) also launch stuff in Firefox instead of Chromium.

Are there any additional settings which affect xdg-open functionality?

Something is definitely broken:

#### Update

I have purged Firefox:

- update-alternatives - uses the Chromium browser
- sensible-browser - opens the Chromium browser
- xdg-open & gnome-open - opens using google-chrome which kindly tells me "it's not default browser"

!!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I set a new xdg-open setting?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/62585/how-do-i-set-a-new-xdg-open-setting)

Answer (score 15):

All of the above answers are basically correct, depending on what you're doing and how the programs you're using are invoking things. For me the problem was that my terminal emulator (Tilix) was still opening the wrong browser (Firefox instead of Chrome), as well as `xdg-open foobar.html` also opened the wrong browser.

Eventually I figured out that there's also `xdg-mime`:

```sh
xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/http
firefox.desktop
xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/https
firefox.desktop
```

That is not correct, so I changed those to:

```sh
xdg-mime default google-chrome.desktop 'x-scheme-handler/http'
xdg-mime default google-chrome.desktop 'x-scheme-handler/https'
```

Then there's also bindings for 'text/html', which I also changed:

```sh
xdg-mime default google-chrome.desktop 'text/html'
```

This, in combination with making sure that the following are also set correctly:

- the `BROWSER` environment variable
- `sensible-browser` (`/usr/bin/sensible-browser`, a wrapper script that tries to launch some of the other items in this list)
- `gnome-www-browser` (`/usr/bin/gnome-www-browser`, a symlink to `/etc/alternatives/gnome-www-browser`)
- `x-www-browser` (`/usr/bin/x-www-browser`, a symlink to `/etc/alternatives/x-www-browser`
- `www-browser` (`/usr/bin/www-browser`, a symlink to `/etc/alternatives/www-browser`)
- all of the "alternative" entries (see  `update-alternatives --get-selections` for a list) that point to a browser.
- The GConf database (See @Isaiah's answer)

This finally opens the correct browser for most situations on my desktop. 2018 is surely the year of Linux on the desktop.

Comment: The `xdg-mime` commands are exactly what I needed! I'm running Manjaro-i3, so I don't have a desktop environment at all. (and the `GConf` and `update-alternatives` answers above don't apply)

Comment: Thank you so much! I was going crazy with Tilix opening Firefox

Comment: XFCE: exo-preferred-applications is the tool to set options for exo-open which is in turn used by xdg-open... so that can screw it up as well.

Answer (score 6):

Chromium also has an option in its preferences to make it the default browser:

[image]

That should work, but it if doesn't, read on:

There are several keys in the [GConf](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GConf) database that determine what browser is launched by `xdg-open`:

- `/desktop/gnome/url-handlers/unknown/command`
- `/desktop/gnome/url-handlers/http/command`
- `/desktop/gnome/url-handlers/https/command`
- `/desktop/gnome/url-handlers/about/command`

Make sure they are all set correctly:

- Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
- Enter `gconf-editor`
- Navigate to the above keys, they should be set to `/usr/bin/chromium-browser %s`.

[image]

Comment: This is better. I have removed firefox package and guess what? `$ xdg-mime query default text/html
firefox.desktop`

Answer (score 5):

In my situation I installed Chromium and made it default. Before that Chrome was default browser.

I tried all I was able to do: setting Chromium default browser, changing *gconf* settings to run Chromium with *%U* variable (https://askubuntu.com/a/41085/94263), changing alternatives to use Chromium as default *x-www-browser* (https://askubuntu.com/a/24052/94263), but nothing helped, *xdg-open* opened new Chromium window with start-page ang couldn't open given link, *sensible-browser* opened Chrome.
I tried to purge Chrome (Chromium was automatically set as default and auto in *update-alternatives*) and install it again, because I need Pepper flash from there, and it became default *x-www-browser* alternative again, and again was open with *sensible-browser* command.
Then I've googled some pages and drew my attention on priority and also discovered that there is *gnome-www-browser* symlink in */etc/alternatives/* too and *google-chrome* was default there. Chrome had priority set in *200* and Chromium - *40*. Google Chrome's priority is higher, so update-alternatives utility installs it as default web-browser automatically as "better version".

I've removed both Chrome and Chromium from *x-www-browser* and *gnome-www-browser*:

```
sudo update-alternatives --remove x-www-browser /usr/bin/google-chrome
sudo update-alternatives --remove x-www-browser /usr/bin/chromium-browser
sudo update-alternatives --remove gnome-www-browser /usr/bin/google-chrome
sudo update-alternatives --remove gnome-www-browser /usr/bin/chromium-browser
```

Then I've installed new alternatives with other priorities:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-www-browser x-www-browser /usr/bin/google-chrome 40
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/x-www-browser x-www-browser /usr/bin/chromium-browser 200
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gnome-www-browser gnome-www-browser /usr/bin/google-chrome 40
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/gnome-www-browser gnome-www-browser /usr/bin/chromium-browser 200
```

I don't know are *'40'* and *'200'* default priorities for all computers or you will have other numbers. It's better to look before by entering

```
sudo update-alternatives --display x-www-browser
sudo update-alternatives --display gnome-www-browser
```

Upd. I've tried to do the same things on completely different system, and priorities were the same as here.

Upd2. If you'll run google-chrome just once, it will change it's priority back to *200* but chromium-browser will stay as default.

This worked for me. Chromium was set up as default automatically and *sensible-browser* is launching Chromium. But still *xdg-open* is opening new blank window.

Answer (score 1):

`sensible-browser` is the command to launch default web browser from the terminal.

Comment: Sure. But I have no clue what `$bzr lp-open` is using behind my back. But whatever it uses, firefox gets selected. I think it is using xdg-open which also is selecting firefox.

Comment: After using DoR fixes, chromium is now opened by sensible-browser.

Answer (score 0):

For me the solution was to run this two commands. Then you only have to select the desired browser from the list.

```
sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser
sudo update-alternatives --config gnome-www-browser
```

Sources: [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/mozilla-firefox/+bug/794720),
[Bugzilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1138161)