# External links are opened as blank tabs in new browser window in firefox

Tags: 16.04, firefox

I installed Ubuntu16.04, and set firefox as default browser, whenever I open links from external apps these are open as blank tabs in new browser window (no actual redirection to site, just a blank tab).

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please add a little more detail? What are some example applications that exhibit this behaviour when opening URLs in the (default) web browser? What happens when you run the command `firefox https://askubuntu.com/` in a terminal? Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: @DavidFoerster I have the same problem for years... When I run `firefox URL` it works as expected (i.e. opens FF on the expected tab, or adds a new tab to the current FF window if it was already open). Any external app shows the same behaviour (from Thunderbird, Evince, Eclipse, ...).
Can it be some Ubuntu "default application" settings?

Comment: @DavidFoerster nevermind, I just got it :) I guess your subconcious sent good vibes to mine ;)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Link clicked not passed to firefox](https://askubuntu.com/questions/41010/link-clicked-not-passed-to-firefox)

Comment: @Matthieu: What helped was probably the same process as in [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging). :-]

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same problem for *years* and was finally able to solve it thanks to this strange new fashion of creating YouTube videos instead of writing a blog post ([here is the original video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?reload=9&v=8a5KW05lRQs)).

Basically, you need to add a missing `%u` parameter in `~/.local/share/applications/firefox.desktop` at the end of each `Exec=` line:

```
$ grep -B 2 ^Exec= ~/.local/share/applications/firefox.desktop
Keywords=Internet;WWW;Browser;Web;Explorer
Keywords[fr]=...
Exec=firefox %u
--
Name=Open a New Window
Name[fr]=...
Exec=firefox -new-window %u
--
Name=Open a New Private Window
Name[fr]=...
Exec=firefox -private-window %u
```