# How can I open irc:// links in Pidgin from Chromium?

Tags: pidgin, irc, xdg-open

I want to open `irc://` links in pidgin from chromium.

When i am logged-in to a irc server(`irc.freenode.net`) running `purple-url-handler irc://irc.freenode.net/#ubuntu` in terminal works fine.

But when i click the same link in chromium (which uses `xdg-open` to open `irc://` links) it does nothing. Any idea how to make this happen?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK I found it!So I will answer here.

### FOR UBUNTU(>=11.04)

Gconf settings(`/desktop/gnome/url-handlers`) didn't do anything since as of Natty the file-open functionality is handled by `gvfs-open`, which doesn't use gconf settings. Rather, gvfs-open looks at the ".desktop" files bundled with each application to determine what file types can be handled.if it is not installed, run :

```
   sudo apt-get install gvfs-bin
```

In all x-scheme handler urls( like irc://, xmpp://, sip://, aim://) are handled by purple-url-handler.We are going to create a desktop file for it.

```
gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/purple-url-handler.desktop
```

& put following content in it:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Purple URL Handler
GenericName=Internet Messenger
Comment=URL handler forGoogle Talk, Jabber/XMPP, MSN, Yahoo and more
Exec=purple-url-handler %U
Icon=pidgin
StartupNotify=true
Terminal=false
Type=Application
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/irc;
Categories=Network;InstantMessaging;
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=pidgin
```

Now to make irc:// links open with purple-url-handler run :

```
xdg-mime default purple-url-handler.desktop x-scheme-handler/irc
```

This informator is stored in **~/.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list**.

Now when you click any irc:// link in chromium for the first time, the following prompt will appear:

[image: chromium-prompt]

Select remember my choice & launch application. If you are already logged in it will open the room in pidgin.

DONE!

Comment: Probably better to use `MimeType=x-scheme-handler/aim;x-scheme-handler/gg;x-scheme-handler/gtalk;x-scheme-handler/icq;x-scheme-handler/irc;x-scheme-handler/msnim;x-scheme-handler/myim;x-scheme-handler/sip;x-scheme-handler/xmpp;x-scheme-handler/ymsgr;` and announce every protocol it supports to the associations system. (I'd also use `NoDisplay=true` so it doesn't duplicate Pidgin's appearance in the menus)