# How to open irc:// links in Empathy

Tags: irc

Whenever I click on a irc:// link in Ubuntu 12.10 (with browser Firefox) it always wants to open them in a web chat thing called Mibbit.

I would like to be able to open them (in a new tab) in Empathy.

Could someone please instruct me on how to accomplish this?

Comment: This might be dependant on your browser as well.

Comment: Added my browser (Firefox) to the Question.

Answer (score 0):

This feature hasn't been implemented yet in Empathy. See bug reports here:

*[Bug 565513](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=565513)*; *[Bug 541156](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=541156)*

However this can be achieved by creating a small `empathy-uri-handler` for this type of uri (I am working on it).

.

---

**For Now:**

You can do it in pidgin.

[How can I open irc:// links in Pidgin from Chromium?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/179628/how-can-i-open-irc-links-in-pidgin-from-chromium)

[Open irc:// links in XChat from Firefox and Chromium](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55779/open-irc-links-in-xchat-from-firefox-and-chromium)

First Create `purple-url-handler.desktop` in `/usr/share/applications` as described in first question (above).
Then using the menu option Edit->Preferences->Applications Tab in Firefox select `"purple-url-handler.desktop"` for the `"irc"` content-type.

DONE!