# How to open text, video, or image files via terminal?

Tags: command-line

I am new to Ubuntu and I would like to know how to open a simple text file or a video file or an image file via the terminal.

Answer (score 77):

If you wish to open files in graphical applications from the command line, such as within `gnome-terminal` or `xterm` then simply run:

```
xdg-open $file
```

And it will open `$file` in an appropriate application for that file. The argument can also be a URL, so

```
xdg-open http://askubuntu.com/
```

will open this site in your browser, and:

```
xdg-open mailto:someone@somewhere.com
```

should open your default mail program's composer, with `someone@somewhere.com` in the `To:` field.

If what you want to view videos on a virtual terminal, without Xorg, you can use `mplayer` with the `directfb`, `fbdev`, `fbdev2`, `sdl` (with the frame buffer back-end), or `svga` as the video output, by running

```
mplayer -vo fbdev2 file.mpg
```

For example. For still images, you can install the `fbi` package, and use it to display images on a framebuffer.

Comment: I forgot about xdg-open.  xD  But they were not specific about whether they have only the terminal, or whether they have the GUI, so I assumed worst-case in that they only have a terminal and no GUI...

Comment: Related: [How do I set a new xdg-open setting?](https://askubuntu.com/q/62585)

Answer (score 4):

### To open a video from terminal

- First install vlc player by running the below commands on terminal

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install vlc
  ```
- Then go into the directory which contains videos you want to play,

  ```
  cd /path/to/the/directory/which/contains/videos
  ```
- Play the video from terminal using vlc player,

  ```
  vlc "videofilename.fileformat"
  ```

### To open a picture from terminal,

- Install shotwell to open a picture via terminal,

  ```
  sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yorba/ppa
  sudo apt-get update
  sudo apt-get install shotwell
  ```
- Then go into the directory which contain picture you want to open,

  ```
  cd /path/to/the/directory/which/contains/picture
  ```
- Open the picture via terminal using shotwell,

  ```
  shotwell "picturefilename.fileformat"
  ```

Answer (score 2):

To open a text file, you can use:

```
nano /path/to/file
```

where `/path/to/file` is the location on the computer your file is stored, with the actual name of the file at the end.

So, if you downloaded your file into your `Downloads` directory and your username is `example`, and the file is named `test.txt`, then you can do:

```
nano /home/example/Downloads/text.txt
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Eye Of Gnome too to open image files:

```
eog filename.png
```

If not installed already, you can install it using:

```
sudo apt-get install eog
```

Answer (score 1):

To open any file via terminal, you have to locate the path of that file.
Then type the name of the application which you want to open the file with.

For example, to open an image file in the current directory using Shotwell, you would run:

```bash
shotwell image.jpg
```

or (using the absolute path of the file):

```bash
shotwell /home/username/Downloads/image.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

I just downloaded a song (Mario theme song (fast)) and ran the following to play it:

```
play main_theme_sped_up.ogg
```

And it worked!

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to [@dobey's good answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/384003/618353), if you prefer opening an image with the system's image viewer via terminal, use `xdg-open` as the answer suggests. Another common alternative for images is `feh`, which can be installed by running:

```
sudo apt install feh
```

and then, for example:

```
feh icon-us.jpg
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `cat` to read the contents of text files:

```
cat $file
```

[`cat` usage (Unix-like operating system command)](http://www.linfo.org/cat.html)

**Stands for:** Con`cat`enate

**Function:** Concatenate files and print on the standard output

**Syntax:** `cat [-benstuv] [file ...]`

Comment: While `cat` will display text files in human readable form but it can't open pictures and videos since the data inside that isn't stored in form of a regular text file.