# how to get links from chrome to open in firefox?

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, extension, xdg-open

Firefox is my default browser but I have to run Chrome to be able to use PWAs (progressive web apps). when I click links in the PWA they always open a Chrome window. I've been playing with appending an `ff:` to URLs and then having `xdg-open` handle the URL with Firefox but no luck so far. I read over the many `xdg-open` articles but I can't seem to get it to work properly. this seems like the cleanest way to go about it, though.

I realize I would need to write an extension to append every URL on the page with `ff:`. I'm on KDE Neon but I think this is applicable here.

Sources already used fruitlessly:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/555110/868274
- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/59088/309372
- https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xdg-utils#xdg-settings

Comment: @Yufenyuy Please review my [edits](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1152127/revisions) as I had to edit yours before accepting.  **;-)**

Comment: @Fabby, Okay. I get it... :)

Comment: I have the same problem, but I'm curious how to get `ff:` on all URLs in the Chrome PWA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so I'll try to help with making urls like `ff:whatever` to be opened in firefox. First, firefox does not know how to interpret `ff:` mime type, so we need to write a simple script that will remove `ff:` from the URL and pass the rest to firefox:

```
#!/bin/bash
firefox $(echo $1 | sed 's/ff://')
```

Place this script somewhere (I'll refer to it later as `/path/to/script`) and don't forget to make it executable with `chmod +x /path/to/script`. 
Next we need to create a `.desktop` file that will handle `ff:` mime and call this script. Good place for this file would be in `~/.local/share/applications/`. You can give it any name

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Version=1.0
Type=Application
Terminal=false
Name=OpenInFirefox
Comment=Open link in Firefox
Categories=Application;Network;
MimeType=x-scheme-handler/ff;
Exec=/path/to/script %u
```

Don't forget to replace `/path/to/script` with path to the script created before.

That's it. Now run `sudo update-desktop-database` and all links that start with `ff:` should open in firefox.