# Where to change how xdg-open opens urls? sync with kde-open?

Tags: kubuntu, kde, default-programs, xdg-open

- `kde-open "http://askubuntu.com/"` is nice, and opens the URL in my webbrowser
- but `xdg-open "http://askubuntu.com/"` opens the link in my texteditor :-(

I know where I find the file-association in KUbuntu, but as `kde-open` works, I guess thats not where the problem is.

Can I sync `xdg-open` to use the same program as the `kde-open`?
Or at least change its behavior for http(s)-URLs?

(The main problem is that some programs, like the `slack-client`, uses `xdg-open` to open files and URLs.)

#### Update 1

`x-www-browser` and `gnome-www-browser` in update-alternatives:

```
update-alternatives --display x-www-browser
x-www-browser - auto mode
  link best version is /usr/bin/firefox
  link currently points to /usr/bin/firefox
  link x-www-browser is /usr/bin/x-www-browser
  slave x-www-browser.1.gz is /usr/share/man/man1/x-www-browser.1.gz
/usr/bin/chromium-browser - priority 40
/usr/bin/firefox - priority 40
/usr/bin/konqueror - priority 30
  slave x-www-browser.1.gz: /usr/share/man/man1/konqueror.1.gz
```

and `gnome-www-browser`

```
update-alternatives --display gnome-www-browser
gnome-www-browser - auto mode
  link best version is /usr/bin/firefox
  link currently points to /usr/bin/firefox
  link gnome-www-browser is /usr/bin/gnome-www-browser
/usr/bin/chromium-browser - priority 40
/usr/bin/firefox - priority 40
```

Both point to `firefox`, no trace of `kwrite`.

Comment: The following post might contain helful informations for you: http://askubuntu.com/questions/18418/how-to-set-which-application-is-launched-by-xdg-open

Comment: @dufte as both x-www-browser and gnome-www-browser points to firefox, it wasn't that helpful :-( but thanks anyway

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It looks like `xdg-open` has internal settings at least I could make it open different browser than the one set within `update-alternatives`.

```
$ xdg-settings --list
Known properties:
  default-url-scheme-handler    Default handler for URL scheme
  default-web-browser           Default web browser

$ xdg-settings get default-web-browser
chromium.desktop

$ update-alternatives --display x-www-browser
x-www-browser - auto mode
  link best version is /usr/bin/firefox
  link currently points to /usr/bin/firefox
  link x-www-browser is /usr/bin/x-www-browser
/usr/bin/chromium-browser - priority 40
/usr/bin/firefox - priority 40
```

To fix that:

```
xdg-settings set default-web-browser firefox.desktop
```

Verify:

```
$ xdg-settings get default-web-browser
firefox.desktop
$ xdg-open "http://askubuntu.com/"
[opens firefox now]
```

Comment: `xdg-settings get default-web-browser` gives `org.kde.kwrite.desktop`

Comment: this answer is indeed helpful, but i get the same as @PugganSe even after i run `xdg-settings set default-web-browser firefox.desktop`...

Comment: 2½ year ago, but I have a vage memory of things sorting out after installing nautilus. By installing nautilus in KDE, the gnome and kde defualt-app settings got glued togheter, and my kde-settings started to work. Don't remember if that solved this issue, or if it wan another issue in gentoo.

Comment: Things depend on how the web browser is called by the other program. If the environment calls an URL, you may want to additionally set the `default-url-scheme-handler` for 'http', 'ftp' (also 'mailto' would be possible), like in `xdg-settings set default-url-scheme-handler http firefox.desktop` or `xdg-settings set default-url-scheme-handler ftp firefox.desktop` (or `xdg-settings set default-url-scheme-handler mailto claws-mail.desktop` for Claws as default 'mailto:'-link program)