# How to set browser for x-ww-browser?

Tags: 18.04, kde, browser

I have different browsers opening with

```
xdg-open www.google.com
```

and

```
x-www-browser www.google.com
```

Where are these commands came from? How to configure the browser, which opens with `x-www-browser`?

Comment: Probably duplicate, try https://askubuntu.com/q/788043/26246

Comment: `sudo update-alternatives --config www-browser`, `sudo update-alternatives --config gnome-www-browser`, and finally `sudo update-alternatives --config x-www-browser`. Read the manual page of `update-alternatives`.