# Firefox snap: make the "Chose application" portal remember my choice

Tags: kubuntu, firefox, snap, default-programs

If I download a text file and then click on it in the downloads list to open it in the default application, the "Choose Application portal" window is opened each time even if I select the option to "always open ... ... chosen app".

It's odd that I am asked *at all* about what app to use: Kate is *already* listed as “default”. —What's a default app if not that to be used without being asked about?— But then, the “Always open” doesn't work. Looks like a bug.

[image]

- If this is expected behavior, is there *a setting to change it*?
- If this is a bug, *what app is involved exactly*?
- *Against which program/package could I post a bug report or feature request*? Is it the bug-reporting platform of Mozilla? Ubuntu? other?

Comment: Check if settings through `update-alternatives` or `xdg-settings` make difference. A case, I have faced before https://askubuntu.com/q/788043/26246

Comment: @user.dz - As said and reflected in image, the default application is already in place and working for all other casses, this is a Firefox-snap problem in Kubuntu.

Comment: Since snap does not really work, I've described how to use Firefox without snap [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/1403392/906933).

Comment: @kanehekili - What I otherwise do is to run Firefox as a "portable" installation: Firefox and other Ff-based browsers can *simply be run from the extracted folder after downloading their archive. Updates are automatic even in this scenario, no PPA needed.* But this is a snap-specific question. I'm not asking for non-snap solutions. (Testing 24.04 we have a bug where non-snap&flatpak Firefox stopped working!) In fact, Firefox snap was the only snap I disliked and only because of the above problem. I can very well live with snap if I fix this problem and that is my intention :) Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Running Firefox on Debian and ArchLinux (no snap) didn't show any problems the last years. I'll try the "extracted folder" version since I didn't know that