# xdg-open can't open applications from links

Tags: kubuntu, xdg-open

I'm using Kubuntu 19.10 and I have a problem with xdg-open.

Every link that redirects to an application doesn't work. For example slack links: I am on their website, when the link of accessing a workspace appear I only get the popup: "Open xdg-open?" and then nothing happens.

Same thing for zoom video calls. I click the link that should redirect me from the browser to the zoom application, same pop-up and nothing happens.

How can I fix it? The only thing that looks correct is the browser, so if I run in my terminal: `xdg-open www.google.com` it opens the window on my default browser

Comment: Also consider asking at https://www.reddit.com/r/kde/ or https://www.reddit.com/r/Kubuntu/.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to set which application is launched by xdg-open?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/18418/how-to-set-which-application-is-launched-by-xdg-open)

Comment: Not really, I have no problem with the browser settings I need to configure other programs (like Slack and Zoom) and I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: Are you using Chromium? I have the same problem and I think it's related to a recent (forced) switch to using the Snap version of Chromium.  If I copy and paste the https://app.slack.com/ssb/add?s=1&v=4.2.0 url into Firefox and sign in, then the xdg-open bit succeeds.

Comment: Having the same issue with LXDE + 20.04. Many programs affected also like Slack, Discord, and Zoom. If I run xdg-open URL manually in a terminal I simply get an error message with my home/user prepended to the URL path (so it obviously fails)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I run Debian Buster
[Stevel's answer here on the Linux stack exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/450200/xdg-open-on-debian-9-fails-to-open-browser) helped me solve it.

To elaborate on how to apply the fix.

1. Open up the the xdg-open file as a superuser so you can edit and save the file.
   You should find the file at usr/bin/xdr-open
   Alternatively run the command `which xdg-open` in your terminal to find the path to the xdg-open file
2. Find the line that reads `if pcmanfm --help >/dev/null 2>&1 -a is_file_url_or_path "$1"; then` using `Ctrl+F` or however you want.
3. Edit the `-a` on that line to `&&`
   Your edited line should read `if pcmanfm --help >/dev/null 2>&1 && is_file_url_or_path "$1"; then`
4. Save and test.

Good luck!

Comment: I change the file accordingly but it didn't change anything :(

Comment: This line should only be evaluated in case your desktop environment is LXDE (e.g. default in Lubuntu), not KDE (default on Kubuntu).

Comment: My line was already the correct one.  So, still have the problem that can't open Zoom - at final step get stuck saying "Open xdg-open".  And, when I click this option nothing happens.  Hmmmmm

Comment: Same - my line was already correct, but nothing happens with xdg-open. Can't open Zoom or similar. Same result in both Chrome and Firefox. Only since upgrading from Linux Mint 19 to 20.