# How to make apt:// urls to open with Gdebi or apturl?

Tags: apt, apturl, gdebi

When I click on a apt:// link in Chromium Ubuntu Software Center handles the link.
How can I change it to gdebi/apturl?

Comment: Refer [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/17186/how-can-i-make-chromium-open-apt-links-with-xdg-open) and [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/18418/how-to-set-which-application-is-launched-by-xdg-open)

Answer (score 5):

Gdebi doesn't have functionality of opening apt: links, however apturl does.There is a way to set default application for x-scheme-handler links with `xdg-mime` command.

First make sure apturl is installed on your system,

```
sudo apt-get install apturl
```

Latest version of chromium already uses xdg-open for any x-scheme-handler links.To configure xdg-open with apturl , go through following steps:

Make sure they are all set correctly:

- Hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>
- Enter `gconf-editor`
- Navigate to the `/desktop/gnome/url-handlers/apt/command`, it should be set to `apturl "%s"`.

[image]

**Now set apturl default for any apt links:**

```
xdg-mime default apturl.desktop x-scheme-handler/apt
```

It will set apturl as default application for apt links.You can check it by running `xdg-mime query default x-scheme-handler/apt` in the terminal(output would be `apturl.desktop`)

Now whenever you click apt in chromium, it will use apturl.

[image]

DONE!!

Comment: How do I do this programmatically?

Comment: What do you men by "programmatically" ?

Comment: I mean change gconf values programmatically from the shell. Then I can script the change so I don't have to change this by hand using gconf-editor every time I install Ubuntu on a new computer. The command `dconf` can do just that. However I don't know if all the keys in gconf and dconf are named the samed way.

Comment: Since natty it does not depend on gconf-value (gconf depreciated, dconf is used now). Instead it uses `apturl.desktop` in `/usr/share/application` which is there by default. open it in gedit. Make sure exec part read like this: `Exec=apturl %u`. Then proceed as described above.

Comment: You can change dconf/gconf settings using gconftool-2 or gsettings. For example, for dconf its something like : `gsettings set com.canonical.indicator.session show-real-name-on-panel false`. http://askubuntu.com/questions/72070/how-do-i-change-dconf-keys-without-a-gui-for-a-post-install-script